# $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" vs $ eval ssh-agent -s

Tags: git, git-bash, ssh-agent

I really confused to these 2 syntax. What makes they different?

Under windows VS code and git bash environment,

`"$(ssh-agent -s)"` works on me

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 966
```

but `eval ssh-agent -s` dosen't

```
$ eval ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yXsZUCscU2gV/agent.960; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=961; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 961;
```

Any explanation will be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ssh-agent -s` *prints* shell commands to be executed. `eval` evaluates those in the context of the current shell, as if entered directly.

`$(...)` is called *command substitution* and will execute the command inside the parentheses, which are subsequently replaced with the output of the command.

So the order of steps is:

```
1. eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   1.1. ssh-agent -s
        (output): SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yXsZUCscU2gV/agent.960; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; SSH_AGENT_PID=961; export SSH_AGENT_PID; echo Agent pid 961;
2. eval "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yXsZUCscU2gV/agent.960; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; SSH_AGENT_PID=961; export SSH_AGENT_PID; echo Agent pid 961;"
   (output): Agent pid 961
```

If you didn't substitute `ssh-agent -s` with its output, then `eval` will simply evaluate/call the ssh-agent binary and show its output – without evaluating the output.

Comment: Thanks for the crystal-clear explanation.